# What are the types of verification which can be used for a social networking website?

Tags: web-development, security

I'm developing a social networking website for a small network. I would like to keep more security on registration process. I would like to keep some verification methods like SMS, Visa and Paypal (if i can have) etc. so please suggest what I can use. The site is developed using Joomla.

Comment: Why don't you use a simple email verification?

Comment: i have it by default., this website is only for tennis players,. players will meet., play match etc., so i want to keep only trusted people in my website as everyone can register, verify their account using credit card is much safer.. i think.. any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: You have to balance between the need to verify and the will of the users to give you certain data. For example, I think no one will give you a credit card verification for a simple website. Besides you have to balance your cost, SMS cost money. :)

Comment: well again! sorry if i haven't explained well enough, this is a website for tennis players, were they can buy, sell, play matches, find players,, etc. a visa card verification is similar to how paypal verifies a user. an sms verification is how google does send code to mobile. but a fake person can have 10 phone numbers and 10 e-mails., but cannot have a fake visa or any credit card..

Comment: "verify their account using credit card is much safer" No it isn't! Just read the news about how much credit-card-informations were stolen around the last year. Try some invitation method.

Comment: If you want to use credit card validation then you have to ask if your users trust you.

Comment: well registering the website is open to all but to access certain feature like meeting players i need to have some strict verification process so that the users in the website will know this person is real., so only after a profile is verified he can access this feature. if not he can use the website like he uses other social networking site., he can uplaod photos, videos etc.,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this by invitation only. Since the sites are non-commercial, having to know me or know someone I trust to get access works quite well.

If you have a commercial intent, then using a paid membership model along with limited rights until certain user levels are reached (much like se works) should work fine for you. Even having users pay a $1 a month for membership will keep out spammers and most other riff-raff.